# how to reduce the time to parse an XML document using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

Uisng NSXMLParser to parse the file  through a URL is pretty straightforward, but when it comes to parsing a file which is really huge its really pain. 
Is there a way to reduce the amount of time it takes to parse the file and give me the results in much faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Try TBXML parser. It´s the fastest xml parser available for iPhone.

Links: [Code](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML-Books.zip), [Guide](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Loading_an_XML_document.html)

You can also read this nice article: [How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Comment: But will TBXML parser be faster enough to parse 4 different URLs than NSXMLParser? I know its a vague query but before using it just want to make sure that if only its possible I can give it a shot.